# Include boost in xcode

Tags: xcode, boost

I could not include boost in xcode.
I used the build instructions from the Boost documentation and wrote the search paths in xcode /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include.

Any help please !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using boost with Xcode 3.2.1 on mac os 10.6.8

I had problems with using boost and Xcode today, finally I managed to make it work so I hope this helps:

1. download boost, I got the 1.52.0 today, untar it
2. install boost:

   at first I couldn't do the `./bootstrap.sh`, it stopped after the first few lines. After some googling, I got the answer, it was because when I installed Xcode a long time ago, for some reason I didn't check the “Unix development" in the install options. At this point, reinstall a newer version of Xcode and check the "unix development line"

   after that, the `./bootstrap` and `./b2` install worked fine
3. the lambda example:

   at this point, the first example should work fine, if it doesn't try adding `/usr/local/include` in the project settings/header search path
4. using thread or something else that requires to be built

   threads require a specific dylib to work: libboost_system.dylib. on my system it was located in `/usr/local/lib` after the `./b2 install` thingy

   in the left part of the GUI, you can right click anywhere and select Add Existing File

   if the file is hidden you can find a shortcut to get to usr/local/lib in the directory `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/local`

once the `libboost_system.dylib` does appear in the Groups and Files part of the GUI, it should work

Comment: Perfect, wish I could give you +10 for keeping my ego of learning c++ alive this Friday night!

Answer (score 44):

I have spent a long time trying to make this work. I could not make it work using the download from the Boost project homepage, so I used [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) instead:

After homebrew is installed, I installed Boost using:

```
brew install boost
```

or, if you don't have python installed, using:

```
brew install boost --without-python
```

Without the --without-python it would not install on my machine.

1. In XCode (4.3.3), select the project file in the left sidebar (top most), and select it again in the project pane.
2. Select the Build Settings tab, and select All.
3. Under Search Paths, add the header search path **/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include/** and check the box. The path should now show in the Build Settings.

Now, you can use:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
```

or whatever you need from the Boost package.

---

In case you have boost already installed, use `$ brew info boost` to get the correct path:

```
boost: stable 1.60.0 (bottled), HEAD
Collection of portable C++ source libraries
https://www.boost.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1 (11,139 files, 436.5M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/boost.rb
```

Comment: Nice! This worked for me in XCode 5 though I added up to `/include/`, not with the boost directory.

Comment: I made a symlink in my homedir to the cellar/boost/1.49.0 dir

Comment: My header search path is like this: $(HOME)/boost_1_57_0/include

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It works for me, but I added `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/boost/1.82.0_1/include` instead, probably because I installed the boost library using brew.

Answer (score 15):

I followed henrikstroem's great post, like this:

Install via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), took less than 3 minutes

```
mac:~ woz$ brew install boost
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/boost-1.57.0.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring boost-1.57.0.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0: 10572 files, 439M
mac:~ woz$
```

Create symlink in your homedir

```
mac:~ woz$ cd
mac:~ woz$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0 boost_1_57_0
mac:~ woz$
```

Inside Xcode refer to the just created symlink like this

[image: Xcode build settings for boost]

For the `Header Search Paths` use `$(HOME)/boost_1_57_0/include`

For the `Library Search Paths` use `$(HOME)/boost_1_57_0/lib`

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this for `bind` but it refuses to work, the `#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>` keeps getting flagged as "file not found".

Comment: On top of this I also added dylib files for respective library.

Comment: Under Search Paths there are a dozen subsections. Two of these are Header and Libary search paths. 

But these are again subdivided into release and debug, which do we use? Why would we ever use one but not the other. 

Why do we have to use both? Surely there should be a way to just refer to "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.68.0_1" and let the Xcode app do the rest?

Answer (score 6):

```
mic@mbp: ~/work $ brew install boost
mic@mbp: ~/work $ ls -l /usr/local/include/boost
lrwxr-xr-x  1 mic  wheel  36 Nov 27 01:06 /usr/local/include/boost -> ../Cellar/boost/1.56.0/include/boost
```

hi, I add `/usr/local/include` in `Header Search Paths` (with double click it, but Debug or other sub checks), then

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main() {
    asio::io_service io;

    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

worked, :D

Comment: Why `ls -l`, and not `ln -s`?